# Is there a way to increase the validation accuracy for this model of image recognition?

Tags: machine-learning, python, image-recognition

I'm really new to machine learning, and this model is supposed to differentiate between rock, paper, and scissors.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import zipfile, os

local_zip = 'rockpaperscissors.zip'
zip_ref = zipfile.ZipFile(local_zip, 'r')
zip_ref.extractall('/tmp')
zip_ref.close()

import splitfolders
base_dir = '/tmp/rockpaperscissors/rps-cv-images'
splitfolders.ratio(base_dir, output = '/tmp/rockpaperscissors', seed = 1337, ratio = (.6, .4))

train_dir = os.path.join('/tmp/rockpaperscissors', 'train')
val_dir = os.path.join('/tmp/rockpaperscissors', 'val')

rock_dir = os.path.join(base_dir, 'rock')
paper_dir = os.path.join(base_dir, 'paper')
scissors_dir = os.path.join(base_dir, 'scissors')

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

train_rock_dir, val_rock_dir = train_test_split (os.listdir (rock_dir), test_size = 0.4)
train_paper_dir, val_paper_dir = train_test_split (os.listdir (paper_dir), test_size = 0.4)
train_scissors_dir, val_scissors_dir = train_test_split (os.listdir (scissors_dir), test_size = 0.4)

train_rock = os.path.join(train_dir, 'rock')
train_paper = os.path.join(train_dir, 'paper')
train_scissors = os.path.join(train_dir, 'scissors')

val_rock = os.path.join(val_dir, 'rock')
val_paper = os.path.join(val_dir, 'paper')
val_scissors = os.path.join(val_dir, 'scissors')

from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
                rescale=1./255,
                rotation_range=20,
                horizontal_flip=True,
                shear_range = 0.2,
                fill_mode = 'nearest')

validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
                rescale=1./255,
                rotation_range=20,
                horizontal_flip=True,
                shear_range = 0.2,
                fill_mode = 'nearest')

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
               train_dir,
               target_size=(150, 150),
               batch_size=4,
               class_mode='categorical')

validation_generator = validation_datagen.flow_from_directory(
               val_dir,
               target_size=(150, 150),
               batch_size=4,
               class_mode='categorical')

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), padding = 'same', activation='relu', input_shape=(150, 150, 3)),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), padding = 'same', activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), padding = 'same', activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3,3), padding = 'same', activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3,3), padding = 'same', activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.6),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='elu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax')
 ])

from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ReduceLROnPlateau
es = EarlyStopping(
    monitor = 'val_accuracy',
    min_delta = 0.0001,
    patience = 10,
    verbose = 1,
    mode = 'max'
)

red = ReduceLROnPlateau(
    monitor = 'val_accuracy',
    factor = 0.3,
    patience = 10,
    verbose = 0,
    mode = 'auto',
    min_delta = 0.0001,
    cooldown = 4,
    min_lr = 10e-7
)

es2 = EarlyStopping(
    monitor = 'val_loss',
    min_delta = 0.0001,
    patience = 10,
    verbose = 1,
    mode = 'min'
)

red2 = ReduceLROnPlateau(
    monitor = 'val_loss',
    factor = 0.2,
    patience = 10,
    verbose = 0,
    mode = 'auto',
    min_delta = 0.0001,
    cooldown = 4,
    min_lr = 10e-7
)

cb_list = [es, red, es2, red2]

model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(),
              optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(
      train_generator,
      steps_per_epoch = 25,
      epochs=50, 
      validation_data = validation_generator,
      validation_steps = 5,
      callbacks = cb_list,
      shuffle = True,
      verbose=2)
```

This is the training result.

```
Epoch 1/50
25/25 - 6s - loss: 1.2190 - accuracy: 0.3600 - val_loss: 1.2458 - val_accuracy: 0.2000
Epoch 2/50
25/25 - 5s - loss: 1.1036 - accuracy: 0.3200 - val_loss: 1.0900 - val_accuracy: 0.4500
Epoch 3/50
25/25 - 5s - loss: 1.0969 - accuracy: 0.3700 - val_loss: 1.0796 - val_accuracy: 0.4000
Epoch 4/50
25/25 - 5s - loss: 1.1017 - accuracy: 0.3100 - val_loss: 1.0607 - val_accuracy: 0.4000
Epoch 5/50
25/25 - 5s - loss: 1.0996 - accuracy: 0.4100 - val_loss: 1.1253 - val_accuracy: 0.2000
Epoch 6/50
25/25 - 5s - loss: 1.1087 - accuracy: 0.3200 - val_loss: 1.1006 - val_accuracy: 0.3000
Epoch 7/50
25/25 - 5s - loss: 1.1033 - accuracy: 0.2900 - val_loss: 1.0933 - val_accuracy: 0.4000
Epoch 8/50
25/25 - 5s - loss: 1.0941 - accuracy: 0.3700 - val_loss: 1.0923 - val_accuracy: 0.3500
Epoch 9/50
25/25 - 5s - loss: 1.0937 - accuracy: 0.4300 - val_loss: 1.1142 - val_accuracy: 0.4000
Epoch 10/50
25/25 - 5s - loss: 0.9846 - accuracy: 0.5100 - val_loss: 1.0261 - val_accuracy: 0.4000
Epoch 11/50
25/25 - 5s - loss: 0.9833 - accuracy: 0.6000 - val_loss: 0.6188 - val_accuracy: 0.8000
Epoch 12/50
25/25 - 5s - loss: 0.7028 - accuracy: 0.6700 - val_loss: 0.5505 - val_accuracy: 0.8000
Epoch 13/50
25/25 - 5s - loss: 0.7925 - accuracy: 0.7400 - val_loss: 0.7147 - val_accuracy: 0.7000
Epoch 14/50
25/25 - 5s - loss: 0.7215 - accuracy: 0.7500 - val_loss: 0.3434 - val_accuracy: 0.8500
Epoch 15/50
25/25 - 5s - loss: 0.5115 - accuracy: 0.8200 - val_loss: 0.4057 - val_accuracy: 0.8500
Epoch 16/50
25/25 - 5s - loss: 0.5340 - accuracy: 0.7400 - val_loss: 0.2904 - val_accuracy: 0.9000
Epoch 17/50
25/25 - 5s - loss: 0.4614 - accuracy: 0.8200 - val_loss: 0.6332 - val_accuracy: 0.8000
Epoch 18/50
25/25 - 5s - loss: 0.4115 - accuracy: 0.8200 - val_loss: 0.2076 - val_accuracy: 0.9500
Epoch 19/50
25/25 - 5s - loss: 0.5848 - accuracy: 0.7700 - val_loss: 0.2534 - val_accuracy: 0.9500
Epoch 20/50
25/25 - 5s - loss: 0.2918 - accuracy: 0.9000 - val_loss: 0.1854 - val_accuracy: 0.8500
Epoch 21/50
25/25 - 5s - loss: 0.4666 - accuracy: 0.8000 - val_loss: 0.2347 - val_accuracy: 0.9000
Epoch 22/50
25/25 - 5s - loss: 0.4083 - accuracy: 0.8100 - val_loss: 0.4281 - val_accuracy: 0.8500
Epoch 23/50
25/25 - 5s - loss: 0.5365 - accuracy: 0.8100 - val_loss: 0.3296 - val_accuracy: 0.8500
Epoch 24/50
25/25 - 5s - loss: 0.5211 - accuracy: 0.8000 - val_loss: 0.1931 - val_accuracy: 0.9500
Epoch 25/50
25/25 - 5s - loss: 0.3975 - accuracy: 0.8200 - val_loss: 0.2931 - val_accuracy: 0.8500
Epoch 26/50
25/25 - 5s - loss: 0.4249 - accuracy: 0.8600 - val_loss: 0.2481 - val_accuracy: 0.8500
Epoch 27/50
25/25 - 5s - loss: 0.3410 - accuracy: 0.8900 - val_loss: 0.4368 - val_accuracy: 0.8000
Epoch 28/50
25/25 - 5s - loss: 0.2647 - accuracy: 0.8600 - val_loss: 0.1591 - val_accuracy: 0.9500
Epoch 00028: early stopping
<tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks.History at 0x7fb704b6b080>
```

Is there a way to increase the val_accuracy or accuracy more?

There are a lot of mixed opinions from the internet. One source suggests adding more layers while another says to reduce it. Why is that?

I tried running it a couple of times, and I know I activated the shuffle function, I get some weirdly different results (This one's max is 0.95, the other one's is 0.50 or 0.75 and so on). Shouldn't I roughly get the same result every time?

And how do I check the overall accuracy of this model?

Sorry in advance if there's any unnecessary functions or variables and mistakes in the codes.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at your train loss vs validation loss. As you can see, in general, your model's validation accuracy is a lot higher than the train. Also, your accuracy oscillates significantly after each epoch. Also, your model is not well-structured, I think. Work on it to make it better fit your model. I would say your model underfit your data, thus, build a more complex model. Or use pre-built, ready powerful models like ResNet, VGG, etc.

Also, from your epochs being run fast, I assume your dataset is small. If it is the case, try to find more data or do data augmentation.

From the training process, I think a better model can learn more from your data. At least, it does not indicate converting to a good optimum value because oscillation of accuracy and loss is big.

If this will still be the case, in your new model increase the epoch size and keep the history of your training process to chose the best epoch which has the highest validation accuracy.